# Purchasing Godaddy SSL Exchange 2010 Server

Tags: exchange-2010, domain, subdomain, godaddy, wildcard-subdomain

I have created a CSR for our Microsoft Exchange 2010 Server (domain: mail.domain.com (example). We have a hosting account with Godady (DNS Hosting only as well). We do not have  SSL Cert and need to purchase one. However, which SSL to purchase? https://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx?ci=9039

We only need a SSL cert for mail.domain.com (https://mail.domain.com) Would the "Protect one website option work?) Godaddy is suggesting we use the multiple domain or even wild card package. However due to only needed a cert for one subdomain/domain (https://mail.domain.com) this is why I this the basic options would be our best option. Do you agree?

Comment: Purchase a *not-GoDaddy-SSL-cert*, for starters ... go with someone good.

Comment: That does not help. Say I go with someone else? Who? Should I get a SSL Cert for subdomains? Wildcard?

Comment: www. certificatesforexchange. com is what I always use and recommend. Simple, easy, done.  (not a plug for them just a recommendation, so I've messed with the URL a little).  You'll need multiple SANs for Autodiscover, external, internal, netbios name even.

Comment: @TheCleaner
Internal and netbios names are no longer available.
https://www.digicert.com/internal-names.htm

Comment: Correct, I'm just rambling from years of it.  It's best to use proper FQDNs on the internal Exchange URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should get the UCC SAN certificate as GoDaddy suggests. You need AT LEAST two FQDNs - autodiscover.domain.com and mail.domain.com.

Never had an issue with Godaddy certs.